# angularjs how to toggle image on click

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to toggle image on click on item. But the problem is when i click on one element, it changes for other element also. i am not able to figure out how to handle such situation.

My html code is ,

```
<div id="TestContainer" class="TestContainer">
     <li ng-repeat="x in testdata.children">
        <img class=opcl ng-src={{PlusMinusImage}} ng-click=ShowHideFunc()></img>
        <img class=testcat ng-src={{myImage}}></img>
        <span>{{x.TagName}}</span>
    </li> 
</div>
```

And code in controller is,

```
$scope.PlusMinusImage = '../Images/Plus15.png';
        $scope.myImage = '../Images/image.png' ;
        $scope.ShowHideFunc = function() {
            console.log("in function ShowHideFunc");    
                console.log(this)
            if ($scope.PlusMinusImage === '../Images/Plus15.png') {
                $scope.PlusMinusImage = '../Images/Minus15.png';
            } else {
                $scope.PlusMinusImage = '../Images/Plus15.png';
            }           
            //event.stopImmediatePropagation();         
      };
```

please help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why tagged `jquery`? it's just `angularjs` code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to manage image key in `testdata.children` array.
For example

```
$scope.PlusImage = '../Images/Plus15.png';
$scope.MinusImage = '../Images/Minus15.png';

$scope.testdata = {
    children: [{
        tagname: "x",
        img: $scople.PlusImage 
    },
    {
        tagname:"y",
        img: $scope.PlusImage 
    }]
}
```

Prepare the children array like this
Then in your html add track by $index and pass the index to your click function

```
``<li ng-repeat="x in testdata.children track by $index">
        <img class=opcl ng-src={{x.img}} ng-click=ShowHideFunc($index)></img>
        <img class=testcat ng-src={{myImage}}></img>
        <span>{{x.TagName}}</span>
    </li>``
```

In your click function

```
$scope.ShowHideFunc = function(index) {       
    if ($scope.testdata.children[index].img === $scope.PlusImage) {
        $scope.testdata.children[index].img = $scope.MinusImage;
    } else {
        $scope.testdata.children[index].img = $scope.PlusImage;
    }

};
```

Comment: Not working. i think ng-src={{PlusMinusImage}} also should be changed.

Comment: Yes.Sorry I was forgot to ad that.Now I corrected it. Hope It helps!!

Comment: It worked.  but it ignores first click and works for subsequent clicks.